# Passing a variable from ARM Template to PowerShell

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

is there any way to pass a variable from ARM- Template to Powershell?

My Power Shell looks like:

```
Param(
 [string] $TemplateFile = 'azuredeploy.json',
 [string] $TemplateParametersFile = 'azuredeploy.parameters.json',
 [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'MyFirstTest-Example'
)
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                       -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                       -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                       @OptionalParameters `
                                       -Force -Verbose `
                                       -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages

Suspend-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -Name "I Wouldlike to use a variable from ARM Template in this position" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
```

the structure of my ARM-Template looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    //My Code here
  },
  "variables": {
    "AzureMachine": "['TestMachine']"
  },
  "resources": [
    //My Code here
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the variable from the outputs in the arm template. Here is an [example](https://gordon.byers.me/azure/azure-arm-templates-example-use-outputs/) for your reference.

**outputs**

```
"outputs" : {
    "vMname" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "value" : "[variables('AzureMachine')]"
    }
}
```

Powershell script

```
Param(
 [string] $TemplateFile = 'azuredeploy.json',
 [string] $TemplateParametersFile = 'azuredeploy.parameters.json',
 [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'MyFirstTest-Example'
)
   $deployment=New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                       -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                       -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                       @OptionalParameters `
                                       -Force -Verbose `
                                       -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages

Suspend-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -Name $deployment.Outputs.item("vMname").value -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I get an exception because of  `Item`: EXception by Calling of `Item`

Comment: @Kaja This should work. Can you check if the name in item exists? $deployment.Outputs.item("vMname").value

Comment: @Kaja You need to start with a lowercase letter for the output name.